# Django Admin: How to set the background-color for a datafield

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a choice datafield and in the admin page I want to highlight its value with a background-color:
YES = green
NO = red

I can set the background-color for a function field (see also image):

```
fields = ['_kw', 'status']
readonly_fields = ['_kw']  
def _kw(self, obj):   
    return mark_safe('<span class="{}">{}</span>'.format(obj.status, obj.kw))    

class Media:   
    css = { 'all': ('myapp/admin.css',) }
```

But I dont know how to achieve this with a datafield. 
Any ideas? If possible, I dont want to customize the admin-template or use a 3rd party app.

[my admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsxfI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your models.py inside of the right class

```
no = 'NO'
perhaps = 'PERAPHS'
yes = 'YES'
STATUS= (
        (no, 'NO'),
        (perhaps, 'PERAPHS'),
        (yes, 'YES'),
        )
```

And then in your admin.py

```
def _kw(self, obj):
    colors = {
        'YES': 'green',
        'PERAPHS': 'yellow',
        'NO': 'red',
    }
    return format_html(
        '<span style="background-color:{};">{}</span>',
        colors[obj.status],
        obj.status,
    )
```

Comment: format_html is probably better than mark_safe, but it doesnt solve my problem. i need the status field to have a background-color. its not a function, it comes from the database.

Comment: Still. Which values can status have? How's your model?

Comment: Your code sets the background of the _kw-field. Thats not what I want.
I dont know how to do this with a datafield. It has no return value.
Perhaps I'm missing something trivial. I'm a noob.

Comment: Just changed from `background` to `background-color`

Comment: Can you share your model?